# concat returns wrong shape

Tags: python, concatenation

I am using concat to merge two dataframes together.   The initial data frames have shape (x,n), (x,m) but the concatenated df has shape (x+1, m+n):

```
print encoded_dataframe.shape
print lcd.shape

lcd_encoded = pd.concat([lcd, encoded_dataframe], axis=1)

print lcd_encoded.shape

lcd_encoded.loan_status_int.isnull().sum()
```

Out:

```
(42533, 3)
(42533, 40)
(42534, 43)

1
```

Comment: .. oh, wait.  Could you check `set(lcd.index) ^ set(encoded_dataframe.index)`?  Maybe the indices don't match up.

Comment: Sorry, not quite sure what you are after here?

Comment: One reason the concatenation could have an "extra" row is if the indices are different.  If you try to concatenate frames with indices [1,2] and [2,3], you'll get one with [1,2,3].  The command I gave you will show the elements which aren't in both indices.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow....apologies, I am a noob!   What exactly am I checking above?    Not sure what set and ^ do?   I included exactly the command you requested, but no output...

Comment: @DSMHere's my output....set([39786, 42533])

Comment: @DSM. - You were right.   There was an indexing problem caused by a dropna() on one of the data frames.    Thanks for the heads up!